# iOS safeAreaLayoutGuide gives full 812 height for iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

This is also described but not answered in [Why does this iPhone X UIView not get safeAreaLayoutGuide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498503/why-does-this-iphone-x-uiview-not-get-safearealayoutguide)

I create a totally-new from-scratch single-view Universal iOS app and add *only* these three lines of code to `viewDidLoad()`. I launch the iPhone X Simulator in portrait mode. Here's what I get:

```
let safeSize = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size
// Returns (375.0, 812.0) — why full size?

let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!
let safeSize2 = window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size
// Returns (375.0, 734.0) — this is what I expected.
```

Why does the root view controller's root view not return the expected safe area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SafeAreaInsets:**

> You obtain the safe area for a view by applying the insets in this
>   property to the view's bounds rectangle. If the view is not currently
>   installed in a view hierarchy, or is not yet **visible onscreen**, the
>   edge insets in this property are 0.

The same is true for the **SafeAreaLayoutGuide:**

> When the view is **visible onscreen**, this guide reflects the portion of
>   the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars,
>   and other ancestor views.

Therefore since the view has not laid out yet in `viewDidLoad` or visible, it is 0.. When you do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, you will see it is non-zero and valid insets are set.