# How to support iPhone X design for the app developed using autoresizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios11, iphone-x

My iOS app developed using autoresizing and deployment target is iOS8.Now I need to support this app also in iPhone X design.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: see this for e.g , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441988/autoresizing-for-iphone-x

Comment: if you given the dynamic calculation, it will automatically adopt for all devices

Answer (score 0):

In iPhoneX we have corners which can be used intelligently for that you need to have somethings different in terms of UI to use it completely.

In autoresizing it will handle at its own for all the devices.